# Error in R.NET - Data frame Object not found

Tags: c#, r, r.net

Folks,
I have the simplest of code that I built for testing R.NET but keep getting an error while debugging. I populate a `dictionary` and then build a simple `R data frame`. Not displaying the code when dictionary is populated. While debug I did that and it's correct.

***C# code:***

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> LiqProductionData = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
Engine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
            REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
            var DataFrame_Columns = new List<IEnumerable>(LiqProductionData.Values);   //column data
            var DataFrame_Colnames = new List<string>(LiqProductionData.Keys);         // column header
            var DataFrame_R = engine.CreateDataFrame(DataFrame_Columns.ToArray(), DataFrame_Colnames.ToArray()); 
            engine.SetSymbol("ProdData", DataFrame_R);        
            engine.Evaluate("source('D:/OFM_R/OFM_R_Example.R')");   // Run the "R" script
            var X = engine.GetSymbol("newProdData").AsNumericMatrix();
```

***RScript Code:***

```
setwd("D:/OFM_R")
ProdData <- as.matrix(DataFrame_R)  #converting the DATA Frame from OFM into R Matrix ProdData
newProdData <- ProdData*100
```

***Here is the error:***

Error in as.matrix(DataFrame_R) : object 'DataFrame_R' not found
{"Error in as.matrix(DataFrame_R) : object 'DataFrame_R' not found\n"}

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I did a mistake in the `engine.setsymbol` statement.
It should be modified as :

```
engine.SetSymbol("DataFrame_R", DataFrame_R);
```